# How to scp self?

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to scp from myself to myself, but am getting `Permission denied (publickey)` errors.  This is more of a edge case of a script, but I feel like there shouldn't be an issue with it.

```
ifconfig | grep inet
# 192.168.11.151

scp -p myport me@192.168.11.151:/opt/some-files .

# My public key exists and is valid enough to reach out to GitHub
cd ~/.ssh
less id_rsa
less id_rsa.pub
less authorized_keys
```

Comment: Can you `ssh` to yourself?  Do you have `id_rsa.pub` in `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Just created an `authorized_keys` file and added `id_rsa.pub` to it.  No I can't ssh to myself.  My key is for `buildbot@adomain.com` but my current user is jenkins.  Is that an issue?

Comment: you can specify keys for specific hosts in .ssh/config. Then you also would not need to specify the port.

Comment: Have you tried with `localhost` instead of the IP? with password authentication instead of `.pub` file?

Comment: Plase show the output of `ls -l ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common issue is to forget to properly set permissions:

```
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh
```

Comment: So this ended up being the case for the directory I was trying to copy.  I had set it as read only, recursively `-R`, but it turns out that directories need to have the executable bit set in order to enter subdirectories and access the files inside.  I also did not have a buildbot@myserver user, just a jenkins@myserver account which I should have been using.

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Nice

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

With the same user create your `.pub` file.

```
user:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
f1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:f7:f8:f9:f0:f1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6 user@host
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|        o+=.. E  |
|       . ++=..   |
|        +.*oo.   |
|       . O.+. o  |
|        S .o.. . |
|          . .    |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
user:~$
```

Insert the key into the `authorized_keys` file

```
user:~$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Transfer again

```
user:~$ scp user@localhost:/opt/some-files .
```

Give a try!